# Library to create Directed graph with edge capacity in C#

Tags: c#, directed-graph

Is there a library or class available to create directed graphs, who's edges support capacity too? (Or I have to create it my self?).

*I want to test max flow algorithm I recently learned*

Comment: Have you looked at the directed graph project on codeplex? http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/

Comment: @George it is .net 3.5 only :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A library with many data structures including Graphs is **[NGenerics](http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/)** (**Dot Net 2.0**)

> ***Data Structures***
>
> **General** - Association, Bag, Graph, HashList, Heap, ObjectMatrix, PascalSet, SkipList, SortedList, Curve,
>   **Mathematical** - ComplexNumber, Matrix, Vectors
>   **Queues** - CircularQueue, Deque, PriorityQueue
>   **Trees** - BinaryTree, BinarySearchTree, GeneralTree, RedBlackTree, SplayTree

Link: http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/
Codeproject Page: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DotNet2Datastructures.aspx

---

Graph class by Microsoft (with weighted edges) - [An Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379574%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#datastructures20_5_topic3)
Graph Class by Chris Forbes in .Net 2.0 (with user defined edge data) - [Chris Forbes Graph Class](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4587&lngWId=10)